# I am using Firebase in Chat Application when I send Message to my friend I am sending Push notification

Tags: iphone, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got following error in Swift can any one suggest or give solution.

```
SUCCESS: {
    error =     {
        code = 401;
        message = "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.";
        status = UNAUTHENTICATED;
    };
}
```

I am sending Push notifications using firebase.

Comment: This is caused when you don't tell your app to request permission for push-notifications. Your app is trying to activate a push-notification but your phone hasn't given your app permission to use push-notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func sendPushNotification(message:String) -> ()
{
        let postParams = ["to":"Set here your receiver push id ","priority":"high","notification":["title":"Title","sound":"default","text":"YourMessage"]] as [String : Any]

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("key=getkey form firebase consol", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParams, options: [])

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (responseData, response, responseError) -> Void in
            if response?.StatusCode == 200
            {
            }

        }).resume();
}
```

Comment: I think you have did mistake in in sending Authorization key in header

Comment: How can i update AppIcon Badge number when i receive push notifications.I added like this   :["to":deviceID,"notification":["body":body,"title":title,"badge":1,"sound":"default"]] as [String:Any],but every time badge number showing 1 only.